# Simple fraction , can someone help

Tags: induction, fractions

$=\frac34-\frac{2k+3}{2(k+1)(k+2)}+\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+3)}$

how can i simplify above fraction please, can someone guide me from beginning to the end?

**help am a beginner**

i took the LCM of both to be **4(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)**

4 into the LCM =(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)
2(k+1)(k+2) in to the LCM =2(k+3)
(k+1)(k+3) in to the LCM = 4(k+2)

therefore 
$=frac\{(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)-2(k+3)(2k+3)+4(k+2)}/{4(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}$

Comment: First and foremost, type out your fraction correctly.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: good, i have been trying my best in papers outside the screen, since friday i couldnt arrive at the answer. moreover, i have made my case known to you that am a beginner. slow and stead, the young shall grow

Comment: good, i have been trying my best in papers outside the screen, since friday i couldnt arrive at the answer. moreover, i have made my case known to you that am a beginner. slow and stead, the young shall grow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you want to put everything over a common denominator, which should be a multiple of all the denominators. Here you would go for $4(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)$.

Now you need to multiply top and bottom of each fraction in turn by the appropriate amount to make the bottom what you are aiming for. So you get
$$\frac{3(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}{4(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}-\frac{(2k+3)2(k+3)}{2(k+1)(k+2)2(k+3)}+\frac{4(k+2)}{(k+1)(k+3)4(k+2)}$$
which equals
$$\frac{3(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)-2(2k+3)(k+3)+4(k+2)}{4(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}.$$
Next you need to expand out each product in the top, and collect like terms. When you've done that you should try to factorise the top and cancel any common factor with the bottom. If you've done it right, you should get a common factor of $(k+1)$.

Comment: thank you so much, more blessing